# Как имплементировать индикатор загрузки в ios?

Tags: ios, swift3, загрузка

У меня есть два графика в виде uiView. Они постоянно обновляются. Обновление длиться долго. Хочу имплементировать индикатор загрузки на место графиков на время загрузки.
Поиски в интернете мне пока не дали результатов. Каким классом лучше всего пользоваться и есть ли тут какие-ниубдь особенности?
Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать нативный UIActivityIndicatorView вставив его вместо графика, а как только данные загрузились удалить активити индикатор и подменить его на график  или использовать библиотеку [SVProgressHUD](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SVProgressHUD). Но лоадер svprogressHUD будет блочить main крутясь по центру экрана, что не очень хорошо. Так что советую вам первый вариант. Если вы приведет кусок кода своей загрузки графиков, то я смогу вам вставить готовый код с UIActivityIndicatorView.